How can I install the React canary version in an existing project?
I want to install a canary version of React into an existing project. I have checked the documentation.
It says I should use Releases in Canary are published with the canary tag on npm. Versions are generated from a hash of the build’s contents and the commit date, e.g. 18.3.0-canary-388686f29-20230503.
Do I need to remove the existing React 18.3.1 and the React-Dom or I should install the canary version along it?
